# how to track amazon polly in google analytics via click event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I Want to track how many users have **clicked** on the **amazon Polly** button and need that data in **google analytics**.

Comment: Please could you share any code you have tried so far.

Comment: NO..I was applying  a click event on button but due to no change in html i was not able to implement it properly